# Asp.net - button onclick events not raising

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm a rookie in .net. I'm using an AjaxToolKit Accordion Control and when I put a button in, the "onclick" event is not raising. When I use a dropDownList, if I select "autoPostBack", the event raises normaly (instead, nothing occours). But with buttons I cannot define the "autoPostBack" (its implicit?). It's bringing me several troubles.

Thank you if you can help.

Comment: Can you post some code, both from the aspx and the code-behind?  There are a number of things that could be missing.

Comment: make sure your button is present inxide the Update Panel. When you use Asp.Net Ajax on things inside the Update Panel and make the call backs and can get updated.

Comment: @chris and @vinayvasyani, I've discovered the problem (moreover two problems): I'm using AjaxControlToolKit MaskEditExtenders and MaskEditValidators, and a PopUpControlExtender. When the form isn't fulfilled correctly, the MaskEditExtenders/Validators somehow disables form submiting. Also, TargetControlID property of popupControlExtender was set to the button in question. In this case, the event isn't raised. But I've discovered this because I made a copy of the page for posting here, as in your suggestion. Please guive answers and I'm voting up. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the problem (moreover two problems): I'm using AjaxControlToolKit MaskEditExtenders and MaskEditValidators, and a PopUpControlExtender. When the form isn't fulfilled correctly, the MaskEditExtenders/Validators somehow disables form submiting. Also, TargetControlID property of popupControlExtender was set to the button in question. In this case, the event isn't raised.